# Laravel and Vue, vue-router link not working

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, vuejs2, laravel-blade, routerlink

I am new to laravel and Vue. what I am trying is to use vue-router to redirect to a specific link. I inserted the `<router-view></router-view>` in the main content with `id=app` and also used `<router-link>` as the code below but when I click on the link nothing happens.

```
require('./bootstrap');

import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'



Vue.use(VueRouter)

let routes = [
    {path:'/dashboard', component:require('./components/Dashboard.vue')},
    {path:'/profile', component:require('./components/Profile.vue')}
];

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode:'history',
    routes
});
import Profile from './components/Profile.vue'
import Dashboard from './components/Dashboard.vue'
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#my-app',
    components:{
        Profile,
        Dashboard
    },
    router,
});
```

(Updated) the `master.layout.php` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
This is a starter template page. Use this page to start your new project from
scratch. This page gets rid of all links and provides the needed markup only.
-->
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="HZsvFtU3E9A4dnKDG46COytoNG7kjLGQGQIkwNyz">
    <title>AdminLTE 3 | Starter</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/css/app.css">
</head>
<body class="hold-transition sidebar-mini">
<div class="wrapper">

    <!-- Navbar -->
    <nav class="main-header navbar navbar-expand navbar-white navbar-light">
        <!-- Left navbar links -->
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" data-widget="pushmenu" href="#"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></a>
            </li>

        </ul>

        <!-- SEARCH FORM -->
        <form class="form-inline ml-3">
            <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                <input class="form-control form-control-navbar" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button class="btn btn-navbar" type="submit">
                        <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>

        <!-- Right navbar links -->

    </nav>
    <!-- /.navbar -->

    <!-- Main Sidebar Container -->
    <aside class="main-sidebar sidebar-dark-primary elevation-4">
        <!-- Brand Logo -->
        <a href="index3.html" class="brand-link">
            <img src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/img/telegram.png" alt="AdminLTE Logo" class="brand-image img-circle elevation-3"
                 style="opacity: .8">
            <span class="brand-text font-weight-light"> Laravel  5</span>
        </a>

        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <div class="sidebar">
            <!-- Sidebar user panel (optional) -->
            <div class="user-panel mt-3 pb-3 mb-3 d-flex">
                <div class="image">
                    <img src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/img/man.png" class="img-circle elevation-2" alt="User Image">
                </div>
                <div class="info">
                    <a href="#" class="d-block">admin</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Sidebar Menu -->
            <nav class="mt-2">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-sidebar flex-column" data-widget="treeview" role="menu"
                    data-accordion="false">
                    <!-- Add icons to the links using the .nav-icon class
                         with font-awesome or any other icon font library -->
                    <li class="nav-item has-treeview menu-open">
                        <a class="nav-link active">
                            <i class="nav-icon fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i>
                            <p>
                                Management
                                <i class="right fas fa-angle-left"></i>
                            </p>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="nav nav-treeview">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <router-link to="/dashboard" class="nav-link active">
                                    <i></i>
                                    <p>Dashboard</p>
                                </router-link>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <router-link to="/profile" class="nav-link">
                                    <i class="nav-icon fas fa-user"></i>
                                    <p>
                                        Profile

                                    </p>
                                </router-link>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                            <i class="nav-icon fas fa-power-off"></i>
                            <p>
                                Log off
                            </p>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <!-- /.sidebar-menu -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.sidebar -->
    </aside>

    <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
    <div class="content-wrapper" id="app">
        <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
        <div class="content-header">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row mb-2">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <h1 class="m-0 text-dark">Starter Page</h1>
                    </div><!-- /.col -->
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <ol class="breadcrumb float-sm-right">
                            <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Starter Page</li>
                        </ol>
                    </div><!-- /.col -->
                </div><!-- /.row -->
            </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.content-header -->

        <!-- Main content -->
        <div class="content" id="my-app">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <router-view></router-view>
                <!-- /.row -->
            </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.content-wrapper -->

    <!-- Control Sidebar -->
    <aside class="control-sidebar control-sidebar-dark">
        <!-- Control sidebar content goes here -->
        <div class="p-3">
            <h5>Title</h5>
            <p>Sidebar content</p>
        </div>
    </aside>
    <!-- /.control-sidebar -->

    <!-- Main Footer -->
    <footer class="main-footer">
        <!-- To the right -->
        <div class="float-right d-none d-sm-inline">
            Anything you want
        </div>
        <!-- Default to the left -->
        <strong>Copyright &copy; 2014-2019 <a href="https://adminlte.io">AdminLTE.io</a>.</strong> All rights reserved.
    </footer>
</div>
<!-- ./wrapper -->

<!-- REQUIRED SCRIPTS -->

<script src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

sorry about indention in code :)

Comment: What is error you getting?

Comment: @ImZedi there is no error but links don't work.

Comment: Here you mentioned code snippets for routet-view and router-link are in same page?

Comment: @ImZedi yes they are in master.blade.php file

Comment: And make sure your laravel route to this master.blade check routes/web.php

Comment: here is my web.php file but I see no errors here.

```<?php


Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

Comment: Can I have source code of your page? Simply cntrl+u in chrome

Comment: Yes, now you can see the updated code above. ( The master.blade.php )

Comment: Yes it's okay, I think u dont have include any component for your home route ('/') so it's showing blank, I suggest you to add sample home component with route path ('/) and try

Comment: @ImZedi still i get no result

Comment: have you checked console? any error??

Comment: Yes but got no error, i do the same process for other projects but this time i dont knw why it is not doing correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is with your target element, you are assigning `id="my-app"` to just outer div of `<router-view></router-view>` making another router methods outside targeted element.

Solution:

Remove `id="my-app"` form the current position and assign it to any root element that can include all vue related elements.

In Your case, it would be better to attach `id="my-app"` to the first div tag just after `<body>` tag.